# Sanctions for Russian military action in Ukraine stopping preparation for G8. Is it important for Russia?

Tags: international-relations, russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, sanctions

In recent conflict of Russia and Ukraine some of G8 countries as sanction of Russian military actions in Ukraine declared they will stop preparation for G8 event in Sochi. But why would Russia be concerned about such statements? Is the G8 membership important? Do they even care about that?

Comment: I think that G8 membership not important for Russia. Its platform to discuss G7 countries with Russia. Another question. USA and other countries have personal interests in Ukraine.

Comment: It is right that you discuss the effect of santions treating the military action in Ukraine as fact. It is correct statement of the question because you should not ask yourself who are these countries who impose santcions (these are world terrorist states and war criminals), what is the Russian military action (to supply the Crimea population the weapons they need) and how many people did russia kill in their military compain (0). You put the right question because if you look at the situation in the broad view, sanctions must be imposed on those who impose them, which is unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from the very beginning. What's the history [G7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_Seven)?

It was created in 1970's, with first 7 countries meeting in 1976. That was a meeting of the leading countries of the western world (or "free world", if you wish).

In 1997, when Soviet Union already falled, and Russia didn't have independent foreign politics, it was included in that club. But later, along with Russian reviving from the nightmare of 1990's, old standoff and contradictions come out again. That finally resulted in western countries decision to held 40th G8 summit in 2014 without Russia, transforming G8 back to G7.

For now, G7 finally become a western "gentleman's club" and nothing more. G7 even [cannot](https://www.businessinsider.com/g7-failed-to-reach-agreement-because-of-wuhan-virus-2020-3) form joint statement. Nowadays, it is a fragment of unipolar world, from the middle 90th - when nearly all questions in the world can be agreed and resolved in G7 terms - club of the winners of cold war. For now, it is just sort of an appendix.

Recently, Russia [denied](https://www.dw.com/en/russia-denies-plan-for-putin-to-attend-g7-summit/a-54051725) its involvement in G7+ summit project (which planned to include India, South Korea and Russia) - just because it is pointless to make a summit without China.

In fact, recently Russia [offered](https://www.brusselstimes.com/all-news/belgium-all-news/health/106857/coronavirus-france-and-russia-want-un-security-council-meeting/) a new format - of "G5" - meeting of a Securty Council members - which may be actual in the modern world

Comment: You know that it used to be a group of six (G6) and originated in the 1970’s?

Comment: @Jan, yes. And so what? How does it relates to the question/answer? Just interesting fact?

Comment: It’s because your answer reads as if the G7/8 originated in the 90’s.

Comment: Interesting. What's changed?) Just the world stopped to be unipolar, nothing more

Comment: The world was nowhere near unipolar in the 1970’s so I don’t understand your comment.

Comment: And I don't understand yours.) What's changed since G7/8 of 90's? It was western club in those times, and it is western club now. But now it is MUCH less decisive - since western countries lost most of its economic and influence powers. And now Security Council/G20 are much more constructive platforms, than G7. Don't you think so?

Comment: My point is that the way your answer is phrased, I am led to believe that the G6/7/8 *itself* is an idea from the mid-90’s. I am pointing out to you that the G6(/7/8) was formed two decades before the 90’s. I feel your answer should address that to prevent misunderstandings. (It’s possible that I am the only one who misunderstands; in that case, you can ignore, obviously.)

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, that may lead to misunderstanding, I'll make an edit. Thank you, and sorry for misunderstanding - I've not catched your point at the start

Comment: Glad we cleared that up ^^

Answer (score 1):

There have been a press conference about conflict with the president of Russia and there was a similar question what he thinks about western countries reaction and possibility of withdrawing from G8 and here's his answer:

> As for the G8, I do not know. We will be ready to host the summit with our colleagues. If they do not want to come – so be it.

Full press conference
http://eng.news.kremlin.ru/news/6763#sel=43:21,43:32;46:1,46:29

Comment: The question was whether G8 membership is important for Russia. What Putin claims is a different issue.

Answer (score -5):

The G8 is made up the richest 8 nations in the world, representing about half the world's wealth in both GDP and PPP. The Group of Five-the five largest developing nations-are also often invited to meetings. More inclusive meetings include the G20. The leaders of the G8 meetings discuss global investments and loans worth billions of dollars that effect nearly every nation and person on earth.

They decide international global economic policy. For instance, since 2009, the group decided to privatize more of the world's global food investment. Around that time the world was struggling to meet increasing food demands. They agreed to the “G8 Action Plan for Climate Change to Enhance the Engagement of Private and Public Financial Institutions.”

The group may share data that can ensure the safety of one another citizens. They keep a list of pedophiles and international terrorists.

Other policy topics include: health, law enforcement, labor, social development, energy, justice and interior, and trade.

Russia would lose significant influence by being excluded from these meetings. Putin should care..a lot...no matter what he says in public. He might be able to meet separately with some of the nations, such as Brazil and China, but I think these nations would want to still be part of the G8+5, as well.

Source: Wikipedia "G8"

Comment: You need to specify more clearly what he can lose by not being in the G8

Comment: G8 was a part of unipolar world, so-called "late-washington world". It dies along with  unipolar world.